# Best way to convert Access Desktop Database for use on Sharepoint 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-access

I currently have an Access Desktop Database stored on a network folder, however we are setting up a customer facing SharePoint Online 365 site and would like users to launch the database through this.

When we were using SharePoint Server I was able to upload the database itself to a SharePoint library but when trying this in 365 I get an error message saying unable to open.

I have read an article that says the database tables can be uploaded to SharePoint lists but they all seem to be about Access Web Apps instead of Desktop databases. If this is an option would I still use an Access frontend uploaded to the library? Does anyone have a link to a site that could explain how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What’s the detailed error message you get? Whether you get the error when you upload the database file to library or open the database from library in SharePoint Online?

I can upload a access desktop database file “databasename.accdb” to a library in SharePoint Online site. And open the database with Access client when click the database in the library.

Besides, Microsoft will stop creation of new Access-based web apps and Access web databases in Office 365 and SharePoint Online starting in June, 2017 and shut down any remaining web apps and web databases by April, 2018. Access Desktop databases (.accdb) are not impacted by this decision.

Reference:  [Access Services in SharePoint Roadmap](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap-497fd86b-e982-43c4-8318-81e6d3e711e8)